# How to implement dynamic view properties in Grails

Tags: grails

Can someone point me in the right direction of the correct feature in Grails to implement dynamically changing attributes in my views? For example, when an instance of a domain class is in a particular workflow step, I want certain field prompts, button labels, and data modify-ability to be specific for that step. I will probably store these attributes in another domain class, but I am not sure how to apply them when I am executing, say, the edit method on the instance of data. Is that were custom tags come in, or do I just replace all those attributes in my views with variable tags and pass the values in from the controller? A search term to get me started is fine. Thanks.

Comment: just pass them with `model` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply @micha. Specifically, I am wondering what the best practice is for dynamically changing the visual aspects of a page(view). I think I answered my question by looking at the views from a dynamically scaffolded domain. For example, field prompts are all in the form:

```
<label for="last">
   <g:message code="employee.last.label" default="Last" />
</label>
```

So you can calculate what all the prompts need to be in your controller/service, or query them from a database, and pass them in along with the data that goes into the fields. I was just checking if Grails anticipated this need and made it easier through some specific aspect of the architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Within a controller action you can return a model (Map). The data from this model can be read within views:

```
class MyController {
  def test() { 
    return [myData: 'hello', myOtherData: 42]
  }
}
```

Within the view you can access the model in the following way:

```
...
<h1>${ myData }</h1>
<g:if test="${ myOtherData == 42}">
   <p>${ myOtherData }</p>
</g:if>
...
```

If you want to return another view with a model from a controller you can use the render method:

```
render view: 'myview', model: [myData: 42]
```

See the section [Models and Views](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#6.1.3%20Models%20and%20Views) from the grails documentation for more details.